# Maximum of $27abc+\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}}a\sqrt{a^2+2bc}$ for positives $a+b+c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Maximum possible value of $27abc+a\sqrt{a^2+2bc}+b\sqrt{b^2+2ca}+c\sqrt{c^2+2ab}$ if real positive numbers $a, b, c$ satify $a+b+c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

This is a problem from an Inequality paper that they gave us. I believe that we have to use Cauchy-Schwarz.
I think that we somehow need to change the under root to a perfect square as the 2ab, 2ac... are giving us that clue. Although I tried to go through that direction, I ended up not knowing how to transfrom it into that, neither knowing if it is solved like this.

Comment: $a,b,c$ are nonnegative?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. I think they should be for maximum value

Comment: Yes sorry, is positive

Answer (score -2, accepted):

without loss of generality $a\geq b \geq c$

$$a^2+2bc\geq0$$
$$b^2+2ca\geq0$$
$$c^2+2ab\geq0$$

subtract first and second equation
$$(a-b)(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}-3c)\geq0$$
similarly,
$$(a-c)(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}-3b)\geq0$$
$$(b-c)(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}-3a)\geq0$$

so, all a,b and c $\leq \frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}$ (from first line of answer)

Obviosly maximum will be achieved when all are maximum, so for maximum  $(a,b,c)=(\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}})$

Comment: Maximum will be achieved when all are equal...the function is symmetrical so yeah

Comment: Why is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} - 3c\geq 0$? (same question for the other inequalities)

Comment: -1 Can you explain subtracting a positive term from another results in a positive term? EG Is $ 1 - 2 > 0$? $\quad$ Obviously there are many positive solutions to $ a+b+c = 1/\sqrt{3} $....  (I don't know why you're getting so many upvotes, or why OP accepted your answer.)

Comment: @CalvinLin My question as well...

Answer (score 3):

Denote the expression by $f(a, b, c)$.

Using $2uv \le u^2 + v^2$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &a\sqrt{a^2+2bc}+b\sqrt{b^2+2ca}+c\sqrt{c^2+2ab}\\
 \le{}& a\sqrt{a^2+b^2 + c^2}+b\sqrt{b^2+c^2 + a^2}+c\sqrt{c^2+a^2 + b^2}\\
 ={}& (a + b + c)\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

Also, by AM-GM, we have
$$(a + b + c)(ab + bc + ca) \ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc}\cdot 3\sqrt[3]{ab \cdot bc \cdot ca} = 9abc. \tag{2}$$

Using (1) and (2), letting $x = ab + bc + ca \in [0, 1/9]$ (using $(a + b + c)^2 \ge 3(ab + bc + ca)$), we have
\begin{align*}
 f(a, b, c) &\le 3(a + b + c)(ab + bc + ca) + (a + b + c)\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}\\
 &= \sqrt 3\, (ab + bc + ca) + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}
 \sqrt{\frac13 - 2(ab + bc + ca)}\\
 &= \sqrt 3\, x + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}
 \sqrt{\frac13 - 2x}\\
 &\le \frac{2\sqrt 3}{9}
\end{align*}
where we use $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = (a + b + c)^2 - 2(ab + bc + ca) = 1/3 - 2(ab + bc + ca)$, and
$$\left(\frac{2\sqrt 3}{9} - \sqrt 3\, x\right)^2
- \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}
\sqrt{\frac13 - 2x}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{27}(9x - 1)^2 \ge 0.$$

Also, when $a = b = c = \frac{1}{3\sqrt 3}$,
we have $f(a, b, c) = \frac{2\sqrt 3}{9}$.

Thus, the maximum of $f(a,b,c)$ is $\frac{2\sqrt 3}{9}$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way.

For $a=b=c=\frac{1}{3\sqrt3}$ we obtain a value $\frac{2}{3\sqrt3}.$

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that:
$$27abc+\sqrt3\sum_{cyc}a\sum_{cyc}a\sqrt{a^2+2bc}\leq\frac{2}{3\sqrt3}\cdot3\sqrt3(a+b+c)^3$$ or
$$2(a+b+c)^3\geq27abc+(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{3a^2(a^2+2bc)}.$$
But by AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{3a^2(a^2+2bc)}\leq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(3a^2+a^2+2bc)=\sum_{cyc}(2a^2+ab)$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$2(a+b+c)^3\geq27abc+(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(2a^2+bc)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}c(a-b)^2\geq0.$$